# Graph API Facebook SDK for PHP Permissions Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-permissions

I am working on Auto Posting on facebook page or group by using graph api. But i get error of permissions but i allow permissions But i face this error. Any one who know about this error.
Code given below. 
I share some images Which error showing me or how to allow permissions.[image]

```
<?php

    require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => '{app-id}',
        'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
    ]);

    $pageAccessToken = '{page-access-token}';

    $MsgData = [
        'message' => 'Hi, My name is Zaheer'
    ];

    try {
        $response = $fb->post('/me/feed/' , $MsgData , $pageAccessToken );
    }
    catch ( \Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e ) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    $GraphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

    echo 'ID :' . $GraphNode['id'];


    ?>
```

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: NEVER post an access token, those are meant to be kept secret. data access with that token expires in 3 months. you should remove it from your question and invalidate it immediately (because it will still be in the history).

Answer (score 1):

Debug your Token: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken

You can see that it is a User Token, not a Page Token. Page Tokens can be generated by using a User Token with the following endpoints:

- `/me/accounts?fields=access_token`
- `/page-id?fields=access_token`

Comment: Can you tell me how to get facebook group access token?

Comment: There is not such thing as a “group access token”. What you need to access specific group features or content, should be explained in the documentation for the respective endpoint(s) in question.

Comment: Ok thanks but i find solution to this its required just used facebook group id to post any message.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use page token. You can easily get one from the the graphi api explorer on the right panel. I was having permissions error. My app type was business and to remove it, I just added all the permissions from the given list and after I added all permissions, facebook asked me to review permissions, I simply kept clicking on OK and everything worked, the error went :D